# Python assignment is returning an error (invalid token)

Tags: python

Today I am learning python and I have assign one int variable in console like this

```
zipcode = 02492
```

But it's return me error like this

```
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Why so, I don't understand it? Please help me to solve this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because Python interprets a number starting with the digit `0` as [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base 8). However, the only valid octal digits are 0-7, so the `9` in your zip code is seen as invalid. Additionally, if you're using Python 3, the format of octal literals was changed so they begin with `0o` now (a zero followed by the lowercase letter o), so you'd still get an error even if you tried to input `zipcode = 02432`, which would be valid in Python 2.

Since a zip code doesn't need to mathematical operations performed on it, it would be best if it was stored as a string.

Comment: @Harman you are quite welcome

Comment: but If i want to perform any mathematical operations then how can i use 9, 8 number ?

Comment: @Harman what sort of math do you need to perform on zip codes?

Comment: Not In zip code, I am new in python, I just want to know I need to perform any mathematical operation then how can I use 9 or 8 Number in int variable?

Comment: @Harman in that case, just assign like usual: `parts = 79345`. It's just when you have a `0` at the beginning that Python thinks it's an octal number.